# Пунктуация в предложении со вставкой "а, верно!"

Tags: пунктуация, вставная-конструкция, многоточие, вставка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше оформить пунктуацию в предложении, не меняя порядок слов? Какие варианты допустимы?

*Кажется, он куда-то уехал... а, верно!.. уехал в Латвию.*

Затруднение вызвано наличием первого многоточия, которое отражает заминку во фразе, и восклицательным знаком, подчёркивающим восклицательную интонацию, когда персонаж вспоминает нужное. Также до и после вставки идёт повтор слова.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

***Кажется, он куда-то уехал... А, верно! Уехал в Латвию.***

Answer (score 1):

Предложенный вариант представляется **наилучшим**, особенно если это не фраза в диалоге, а **мысли** персонажа:

*Кажется, он куда-то уехал... **а, верно!..** уехал в Латвию.*

**Повтор** слова выгляди обоснованно (это не тавтология), **восклицательный** знак поставлен по правилам.

[Источник](https://videouroki.net/video/22-chto-nuzhno-znat-o-znakah-na-konce-predlozheniya-258.html):

Многоточие может появляться не только в конце, но и **в середине** предложений. Часто это происходит, когда мы показываем **прерывистость**, нечёткость мысли.

*И тогда… постойте, **не могу припомнить**… тогда подошёл человек… сказал несколько слов…*

[О восклицательном знаке в середине предложения](https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/pravila-russkoj-orfografii-i-punktuacii/znak-vosklicatelnyj)

Примечание 2. В восклицательных предложениях знак восклицательный может ставиться после каждого однородного члена для обозначения **эмоциональной прерывистости речи,** например: Пил мертвую! не спал ночей до девяти!  Всё отвергал: законы! совесть! веру!